# Flutter Web: URL Changes Back to /root After Navigation

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, url-routing

I'm developing a Flutter web application and encountering an issue with the URL navigation. Whenever I navigate to a specific route in my app, the URL initially updates correctly, but then immediately changes back to `http://localhost:58136/root`, even though the correct page remains displayed.

```
dart
   onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
     log('Route: ${settings.name}');
     final uri = Uri.parse(settings.name!);
     if (uri.pathSegments.length == 2 && uri.pathSegments.first == 'video') {
       final videoId = uri.pathSegments[1];
       return CustomVideoRoute(videoId);
     }
     // Other route handling logic
     return null;
   },
```

CustomVideoRoute Class: I have a custom route class for handling video pages, which seems to work fine initially.

URL Strategy: I'm using PathLocationStrategy to remove the hash from the URLs.

The issue occurs when I navigate to a route like /video/123. The URL in the browser updates momentarily to http://localhost:58136/video/123 and then reverts to http://localhost:58136/root. However, the content of the /video/123 page is still displayed correctly.

I've tried debugging and reviewing my routing logic, but can't seem to find why the URL is reverting. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insights into what might be causing this behavior?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!